# Update React [Native] View on Day Change

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, settimeout, react-native

I'm working on a React Native component that should update itself when the day changes, even when the user hasn't interacted with the view.

Is `setInterval` the only way to deal with this? If I call `setTimeout` in `viewDidLoad` specifying the number of ms until the next day, won't the interval be inaccurate if the app gets paused? Alternatively, I could run a periodic timer, but I'd need to give it a short interval so that there's not an apparent delay when the day changes -- seems pretty inefficient.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you can check when the app is resumed somehow, maybe you need to write some ObjC or Java code, that should help :)

Comment: That kinda defeats the purpose of React Native, doesn't it?

Comment: Not really :) not all the native features had been implemented in React Native yet (and maybe they won't be implemented). So that's why it is really easy to create native extension with it, see here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this is more of a general app architectural concern. The simplest answer is you should take the current time in seconds (`new Date().getTime()`), determine how many seconds there are until the next day, and set a timer for that number.

However, as you mentioned, once the app is killed, that timer will no longer be accurate.

You should use [AppStateIOS](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstateios.html#content) to listen for when the app is backgrounded and foregrounded. Upon being sent to the background, clear the timer. Upon being brought to the foreground, run the original calculation again and generate a new timer.

Unfortunately there is no equivalent functionality on Android as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-midnight](https://github.com/ravnhq/react-native-midnight) which subscribes to native APIs and fires event listeners when the day has changed from either a timezone change or crossing the midnight threshold.

Comment: it won't work when application is closed/removed from recent task list/force close/not in memory. any other ways?

Comment: If your app is quit or closed then this question probably doesn't match your problem right? The question here is how to update something in the app when the day changes, if your app is closed there's nothing to update and should have a fresh set of data when it's opened?